# Get all month from colums sql in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, android-studio

I have table "TableHome", column name "Date" in database "DatabaseHome.db" contains data like this

```
5 January 2021
6 October 2021
10 December 2021
```

I want to take the month name for each year to generate monthly statistics, what sytax should I use in sql? and how to have that data converted into arraylist in java without duplicate items?

Comment: Hasn’t you database got a `date` data type? Use it!

Comment: Are you really storing dates as text? What exactly is the data type of your column?

Comment: My data type is TEXT, I have found a solution even though it is a little complicated, but if there is an easier sql syntax it will be very helpful because I am new to using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the above dates to month int values use

```
SELECT month(str_to_date('10 December 2021', '%d %M %Y')) as month;
```

To summarise for a month you need to sum(or count depending what you want) and group by column one,

so something like

```
SELECT month(str_to_date(dateCol, '%d %M %Y')) as month, 
                         sum(someOtherCol) from mytable group by 1;
```

Comment: Does this only work for month names in English?

Comment: %M Full month name in current locale (Variable lc_time_names).  ref https://mariadb.com/kb/en/str_to_date/

Comment: I tried to use the month name in Indonesian but it returns null

Comment: Check the variable `SELECT @@lc_time_names;`  Is your DB set for Indonesian?

Comment: In en-Us hehe. Can you tell how to change it? and do I also have to change this in my mysql java?

Comment: If it is `id_ID  Indonesian - Indonesia` then try `SET lc_time_names = 'id_ID';`  It is really beyond the scope of this question, how to set your DB for different locales.

Comment: I believe I have answered the question that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with `MONTHNAME(DATE)` to get Month in String and `DISTINCT` to remove dupilcate items

```
select distinct(monthname(str_to_date(col1, '%d %M %y'))) as month
from table1
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a1c20da4b92393a0dac888d67540fa38)